# How do I turn off a Steam Controller connected to a Steam Link?

Tags: controllers, steam-in-home-streaming, steam-link

Is there a way to turn off the controller without turning off the Steam Link?  I use the controller to turn on the Steam Link, but I don't actually like it and would like to play with a PS4 controller.  However, the Steam Controller just stays on, wasting its batteries...

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the solution listed there does not work for SteamOS.

Comment: The answer remains the same: hold the Steam-Button for a couple seconds and the controller will turn off.

Comment: @Marv: Unless they updated the firmware in the last week, that does not work.  That's the first thing I tried.

Comment: Well then I suggest that you update your firmware ;)